# python sort multi-dimensional lists CASE INSENSITIVE

Tags: python

I have a list of different expressions. It looks like this:
`my_list = [[1 ,2 ,'M' ,2], [1 ,2 ,'A' , 1], [1 ,2 ,'g' ,3], [1 ,2 ,'o' ,4]]`

I want to sort the list. The key should always be the first entry in the list, in this case the book positions A, M, g, o. However, upper and lower case should be ignored.

In python I used:
`my_list.sort(key = itemgetter (3))`

Output is:
`[[1, 2, 'A', 1], [1, 2, 'M', 2], [1, 2, 'g', 3], [1, 2, 'o', 4]]`

The problem is that in my result the uppercase letters are sorted first and then the lowercase letters. How can I make lower and upper case letters sort together? The result should look like this:
`[[1 ,2 ,'A' ,1], [1 ,2 ,'g' ,3], [1 ,2 ,'M' ,2], [1 ,2 ,'o' ,4]]`

Comment: "The key should always be the first entry in the list, in this case the book positions A, M, g, o." You lost me here. The letters are always at the third position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `key=lambda lst: lst[2].lower()`.

Comment: What do you think about using casefold instead? `lst[2].casefold()`

Comment: @DaniMesejo Depends on the use case entirely. For now I'm assuming that OP does not expect `'ß'` to be treated like `'ss'`.

Comment: both works well, I use now ```key=lambda lst: lst[2].casefold()```